# GDAL 3.1.2 / PROJ 6.2.1 / GCC 10.2 Unable to handle Shape File

Tags: python-3.x, gcc, gdal

**Overall Error**: gdal_polygonize.py fails with "Cannot guess driver for"  I am at a loss here, I have been playing with dependencies and libraries and things but I am getting no where.  I believe the error is somehow the compile is not building in shape file support, but as that is default I do not understand.

**Details**

I am compiling GCC 10.2 (from source) and all the deps for GDAL using the GCC 10.2 compiler.  At runtime when reading a TIFF file to convert to SHP file using gdal_polygonize.py I get a failure about not being able to determine the type.  Normal GDAL commands seem to complete normally such as gdalinfo.

I messed with the python gdal_polygonize and see that it is finding drivers.  I do not see one for shape files though.

I am also compiling Python3.8.8 from source, which is working fine.  I have also tried it with the amazon version 3.8.5 using a yum install, there is no difference on that.

**Error as Reported at Runtime**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/bin/gdal_polygonize.py", line 163, in 
> frmt = GetOutputDriverFor(dst_filename)   File "/usr/bin/gdal_polygonize.py", line 85, in GetOutputDriverFor
> raise Exception("Cannot guess driver for %s" % filename) Exception: Cannot guess driver for ./test.shp

Input is : test.TIF which exists and reports fine from gdalinfo

**GDAL Compile** (Completes without error)

> ./configure  \    --prefix=/usr \    --with-proj=/usr \
> LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib -lz -lopenjp2 -ltiff" \    CXXFLAGS="-Wall
> -std=c++14" \    --with-threads \    --with-hide-internal-symbols \    --with-libtiff \    --with-geotiff=internal --with-rename-internal-libgeotiff-symbols \    --with-rename-internal-shapelib-symbols=yes \    --with-geos \    --with-curl \    --with-zstd \    --with-openjpeg \    --with-xerces-c \    --with-libdeflate=yes \    --with-liblzma=yes \    --with-cpp14 
> --with-python=/usr/bin/python3.8 \    OPENJPEG_CFLAGS="-lopenjp2" && make -j 32 && make install

**GDAL Reports at Build Time:**

You can see it does not show shape files in the supported files.

> misc. gdal formats:        aaigrid adrg aigrid airsar arg blx bmp bsb cals ceos ceos2 coasp cosar ctg dimap dted e00grid elas envisat ers fit gff gsg gxf hf2 idrisi ignfheightasciigrid ilwis ingr iris iso8211 jaxapalsar jdem kmlsuperoverlay l1b leveller map mrf msgn ngsgeoid nitf northwood pds prf r raw rmf rs2 safe saga sdts sentinel2 sgi sigdem srtmhgt terragen til tsx usgsdem xpm xyz zmap rik ozi grib eeda plmosaic rda wcs wms wmts daas rasterlite mbtiles pdf
> disabled gdal formats:
> misc. ogr formats:         aeronavfaa arcgen avc bna cad csv dgn dxf edigeo flatgeobuf geoconcept georss gml gmt gpsbabel gpx gtm htf jml mapml mvt ntf openair openfilegdb pgdump rec s57 segukooa segy selafin shape sua svg sxf tiger vdv wasp xplane idrisi pds sdts nas ili gmlas ods xlsx amigocloud carto cloudant couchdb csw elastic ngw plscenes wfs gpkg vfk osm

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally tracked this down by accident.

When I compiled gdal I used the following command.

> make -j 32 CXXFLAGS="-O3"

It does not like this for whatever reason.

> make -j 32

Works without issue.  I am guessing the C++ opt is causing a problem.